# Testing inner logic of method using vue-test-utils with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, frontend, vue-test-utils

How can I test the inner logic of the following method?

For example:

```js
async method () {
  this.isLoading = true;
  await this.GET_OFFERS();
  this.isLoading = false;

  this.router.push("/somewhere");
}
```

So I have the method that toggles `isLoading`, calls an action, and routes somewhere. How can I be sure that `isLoading` was toggled correctly (true before action call and false after)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract this.isLoading rows into a new method setLoading() and check if it was called.

Comment: Is this really only one way? Jest (or testing in general) pattern is to block up the code?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, but you can't analyze the way function you are testing executes. Only by checking if it DO something by calling other functions. Actually if you want to have your function to be good fit for testing purposes you have to separate data using inside the function from the outer data. So it could be a more pure. Would you create a test sandbox with your case on code sandbox and give us a link?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `shallowMount`/`mount` is the [mounting options](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#data) that could be used to override the component's data props upon mounting. This lets you pass in a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) that mocks the `isLoading` data prop, which then allows you to verify the property was modified within the method under test:

```js
it('sets isLoading', () => {
  const isLoadingSetter = jest.fn()

  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
    data() {
      return {
        // This setter is called for `this.isLoading = value` in the component.
        set isLoading(value) {
          isLoadingSetter(value)
        }
      }
    }
  })


  //...
})
```

Then, you could use [`toHaveBeenCalledTimes()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber) along with [`isLoadingSetter.mock.calls[]`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-property) to examine the arguments of each call to the mocked setter. And since you want to test the effects of the `async` method, you'll have to `await` the method call before making any assertions:

```js
it('sets isLoading', async () => {
  //...

  await wrapper.vm.method()

  expect(isLoadingSetter).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
  expect(isLoadingSetter.mock.calls.[0][0]).toBe(true)
  expect(isLoadingSetter.mock.calls.[1][0]).toBe(false)
})
```

If you also want to verify that `GET_OFFERS()` is called, you could use [`jest.spyOn()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) on the component's method *before* mounting:

```js
it('gets offers', async () => {
  const getOfferSpy = jest.spyOn(MyComponent.methods, 'GET_OFFERS')
  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, /*...*/)
  await wrapper.vm.method()
  expect(getOfferSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```